# Unit test for apex class

Tags: unit-test

I'm writing a test class to cover my code but I have no coverage although .. 
Here is my testmethod:

```
 public static void ChangeCaseTeam(List < case > CasesList) {
    Map<id,Case> mapidCaseCase = new Map<id,Case>(casesList);
    Set<id> casesId = mapidCaseCase.keySet();
    CaseTeamRole ctr = new CaseTeamRole();
    List<CaseTeamMember> ctmTodelete = new List<CaseTeamMember>();
    List<CaseTeamMember> ctmToInsert = new List<CaseTeamMember>();
    List<CaseTeamMember> ctm = [Select id, memberId, ParentId, TeamRoleId from CaseTeamMember where ParentId in :casesId ];
    Map<id, List<CaseTeamMember>> CaseCTM = new Map<id, List<CaseTeamMember >>();

    for(CaseTeamMember mem :ctm){
        if(CaseCTM.get(mem.ParentId)==null) CaseCTM.put(mem.ParentId,new List<CaseTeamMember>());
        CaseCTM.get(mem.ParentId).add(mem);
    }

    ctr = [Select id, AccessLevel, Name from CaseTeamRole where Name like :Label.RoleOwner limit 1];
    for(case c :CasesList){
        for(CaseTeamMember m :CaseCTM.get(c.id)){
            if(m.TeamRoleId == ctr.Id) ctmTodelete.add(m);
            if(m.MemberId == c.OwnerId) ctmTodelete.add(m);
        }
        CaseTeamMember ctme = new CaseTeamMember();
        ctme.MemberId = c.OwnerId;
        ctme.ParentId = c.Id;
        ctme.TeamRoleId = ctr.Id;
        ctmToInsert.add(ctme);
    }
    delete ctmTodelete;
    insert ctmToInsert;
}
```

here is the trigger calling this method:

```
  if((Trigger.newMap.get(c.Id).OwnerId!=Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).OwnerId)) CasesOwnerChange.add(c);


  if(CasesOwnerChange.size()!=0){

    TR06_AffectCaseTeam.ChangeCaseTeam(CasesOwnerChange);
}
```

and my test method

```
   static testMethod void ChangeCaseTeamTEST(){

    Profile p;
    List<Profile> profileList = [SELECT id FROM profile where NAME like '%sys%'];
    if (profileList.size()>0) 
        p=profileList.get(0); 
    User u = new User(alias = 'kbra', email='kbrazi@noemail.com',
                            emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='fr',
                            localesidkey='fr_FR_EURO', profileid = p.Id, country='France',
                            timezonesidkey='Europe/Paris', username='KBrazi@noemail.com',
                            IsActive = true);
    insert u; 
    User u1 = new User(alias = 'kbra', email='kbrazi@salesforce.com',
                            emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='fr',
                            localesidkey='fr_FR_EURO', profileid = p.Id, country='France',
                            timezonesidkey='Europe/Paris', username='KBrazi@salesforce.com',
                            IsActive = true);
    insert u1; 
    Account pAcc = new Account(Group__c=true, Name = 'Parent Account', status__c=system.label.Account_status_customer,BillingCountry='FRANCE' );
    insert pAcc;
    Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Child Account', Parent=pAcc, status__c=system.label.Account_status_customer,BillingCountry='FRANCE' );
    Insert acc;
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName='BRAZI', Account= acc, Title='Mrs', Email='kbrazi@salesforce.com');
    insert con;


    Case c = new Case();
    c.Type = 'Complaint';
    c.Status = 'Created';
    c.AccountId = acc.Id;
    c.ContactId = con.Id;
    c.OwnerId = u1.Id;
    c.Coordinator__c = u1.Id;
    c.Origin = 'Customer Service Input';
    insert c;

    Case c1 = new Case();
    c1.Type = 'Complaint';
    c1.Status = 'Created';
    c1.AccountId = acc.Id;
    c1.ContactId = con.Id;
    c1.OwnerId = u1.Id;
    c1.Coordinator__c=u1.Id;
    c1.Origin = 'Customer Service Input';
    insert c1;



    CaseTeamRole ctr = new CaseTeamRole();
    ctr=[select Id, AccessLevel from CaseTeamRole where Name like 'Case Owner' limit 1];



    CaseTeamRole ctr1 = new CaseTeamRole();
        ctr1=[select Id, AccessLevel from CaseTeamRole where Name like 'GAM' limit 1];
    /*ctr1.Name='User';
    ctr1.AccessLevel='Read';
    insert ctr1;*/
       List<CaseTeamMember> CTMs = new List<CaseTeamMember>();

    CaseTeamMember ctmem = new CaseTeamMember();
    ctmem.TeamRoleId = ctr.Id;
    ctmem.MemberId = u1.Id;
    ctmem.ParentId = c.Id;
    CTMs.add(ctmem);



    CaseTeamMember ctmem1 = new CaseTeamMember();
    ctmem1.TeamRoleId = ctr1.Id;
    ctmem1.MemberId = con.Id;
    ctmem1.ParentId = c.Id;

    CTMs.add(ctmem1);
    insert CTMs;

    ctmem1.TeamRoleId = ctr.Id;
    update ctmem1;

}}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You never call this method in your test class - `ChangeCaseTeam()`

Comment: I'm testing the logic of this method

Comment: Is that method called from a trigger? Can you provide more code from the original class and explain how it's all working?

Comment: Yes it does. A caseBeforeUpdate. I modified my question to include the trigger call

Answer (score 2):

To get coverage of ChangeCaseTeam method which is called from trigger whenever the Owner of the case is changed, you need to change your owner of the case in your test class.

So add the following lines after the insertion of the case.

```
Case c = new Case();
c.Type = 'Complaint';
c.Status = 'Created';
c.AccountId = acc.Id;
c.ContactId = con.Id;
c.OwnerId = u1.Id;
c.Coordinator__c = u1.Id;
c.Origin = 'Customer Service Input';
insert c;
// Update the ownerId of Case to another user which is inserted in the test method
c.OwnerId = u.Id;
update c;
```

Hope it helps.